# JavaScript New Date from a 12 hour format date and time string

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime, time

Example string: `2014-12-31 11:59 pm`

As it stands, JavaScript isn't even parsing the time as the resulting time code returns 12:00 am regardless of what time I provide.

Output after `new Date("2014-12-31 11:59 pm")` results in: `2014-12-31 12:00 am`

**EDIT:**

Even after expecting a format and manually parsing the string, the `new Date()` constructor isn't behaving...

```
var sourceTime = "2014-12-31 11:59 pm";

var dateRaw = sourceTime.split(' ');
var dateYMD = dateRaw[0].split('-');
var dateTime = dateRaw[1].split(':');
var dateAmPm = dateRaw[2].toLowerCase();

// Adjust human month to system month...
dateYMD[1] = (parseInt(dateYMD[1]) - 1).toString();

// Convert 12h to 24h...
if(dateAmPm == 'pm') {
  if(parseInt(dateTime[0]) < 12) dateTime[0] = (parseInt(dateTime[0])+12).toString();
} else {
  if(parseInt(dateTime[0]) == 12) dateTime[0] = 0;
}

console.log(dateYMD);
console.log(dateTime);

var dateParsed = new Date(dateYMD[0], dateYMD[1], dateYMD[2], dateTime[0], dateTime[1]);
```

The console log shows the correct values being passed into `new Date()` but I'm still getting an incorrect output :(

Comment: `new Date()` should result in the current time, there seems to bee a problem with your clock

Comment: @Rialgar Sorry, I made an update to clarify. I was feeding the example string into `new Date()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the standard `Date` from JavaScript I always use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) when working with dates. It makes is very easy to work with different formats of dates and customizing everything.

In your case you could do something like:

```
var datestr = "2014-12-31 11:59 pm";
var date = moment(datestr,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a")
$("#log").text(date.format("HH:mm:SS MMM DD YYYY"));
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8UpA/) to try it.

Comment: How large is this library? I was hoping to not have to add too much overhead with scripting if possible.

Comment: it's 29Kb, 10Kb gz. Pretty big if all you need to do is parse the date. If you have to do more, it's worth it.

Comment: Well, there are other date pieces this could vastly simplify. For now I'm penciling in your answer as accepted unless someone can come up with a native solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no possibility to change the format of the Date String parsed by the Date constructor or Date.parse() in JavaScript. Format specifications can be found at [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) or [ECMAScript Standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), and neither does support am/pm.

(links taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

Answer (score 0):

I'm fixed my problem.. Solution..

```
 let ThisDate = this.startDate0;
 let FinalYear = ThisDate.substring(6,10);
 let FinalMonth = ThisDate.substring(3,5);
 let FinalDay = ThisDate.substring(0,2);
 let FinalHour = ThisDate.substring(11, 13);
 let FinalMinutes = ThisDate.substring(14,16);
 let FinalDate = FinalYear + "-" + FinalMonth + "-" + FinalDay + " " + FinalHour + ":" + FinalMinutes;
```